# laravel 5 how to insert data into 3-4 models many to one relations with form in

Tags: php, laravel

i have a property model for example that this property has so much of features like 40 or more i made one to many realtion ship between property and features and every property can be reserved so this reserve model has a one to many relation too with property now when i want to make property i want to insert into property table features table and reserve table data how can i achive that ? here is some part of code

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('properties', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('type');
        $table->text('title');
        $table->longText('description');
        $table->longText('image');
        $table->float('base_price');
        $table->dateTime('available_start');
        $table->dateTime('available_end');
        $table->integer('base_availability');
        $table->integer('base_capacity');
        $table->integer('max_occupancy');
        $table->float('extra_price');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and the reserve migration :

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('reserve', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('property_id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->float('payable_price');
        $table->dateTime('reserve_start');
        $table->dateTime('reserve_end');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and the features

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('features', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('title');
        $table->integer('property_id');

    });
}
```

Comment: Where is the problem? Create property then create reserve and feature. What's the error?

Comment: @Tpojka i want to make them all with 1 form is that possible ??? create 3 model in 1 form i want user to enter all detail in 1 form

Comment: Sure. After you validate all fields pass certain fields as array to respective model. Don't forget to pass property_id to other models. That's why you have to create property first.

Comment: @Tpojka thanks for the help i will try it